# Pyspark 'from_json', dataframe return null for all json columns

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Utilizing python (version 3.7.12) and pyspark (version 2.4.0).

I am trying to use a from_json statement using the columns and identified schema. **However, the df returns as null**. I am assuming I am incorrectly identifying the schema and type for the columns.

The following code is the json string from a table I pulled from using get_json_object :

```
df = df.select(col('id'), get_json_object(col("pulled_col"), "$.data"))

df.head()

#Row(id = '0123456', data = '[
#{"time" : [], "history" : [], "zip" : "78910", "phnumber" : #"5678910123", "name" : "-"},
#{"time" : [], "history" : [], "zip" : "78920", "phnumber" : #"5678910123", "name" : "-"},
#{"time" : [], "history" : [], "zip" : "78930", "phnumber" : #"5678910123", "name" : "-"},
#{"time" : [], "history" : [], "zip" : "78910", "phnumber" : #"5678910123", "name" : "-"}
#]')

df.printSchema()

#root
# |-- id: string (nullable = true)
# |-- data: string (nullable = true)

df.show()

#+-------+----------------------------+
#|     id|                        data|
#+-------+----------------------------+
#|0123456|[{"time" : [], "history"....|
#|0123456|[{"time" : [], "history"....|
#+-------+----------------------------+

test = df.select(col("id"), get_json_object(col("data"),"$.zip")\
         .alias("zip"))\
         .show(truncate=False)

# The output shouldn't be null?

#+-------+----+
#|     id| zip|
#+-------+----+
#|0123456|null|
#|0123456|null|
#+-------+----+

schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField('zip', StringType(), True),
        StructField('phnumber', StringType(), True),
        StructField('name', StringType(), True)
    ]
)

data_json = df.withColumn("data", from_json("data", schema))\
            .select(col('id'), col('data.*'))

# The df output shouldn't be null for the new json schema?

data_json.show()

#+-------+----+---------+-----+
#|     id| zip| phnumber| name|
#+-------+----+---------+-----+
#|0123456|null|     null| null|
#|0123456|null|     null| null|
#+-------+----+---------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data` column actually contains a json **array** so the schema must be an `ArrayType`:

```py
schema = ArrayType(
    elementType = StructType(
        [
            StructField('zip', StringType(), True),
            StructField('phnumber', StringType(), True),
            StructField('name', StringType(), True)
        ]
    )
)
data_json = df.withColumn("data", F.from_json("data", schema))
```

which results in the following schema:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- zip: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- phnumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

Now if you want each element of the array in a separate row, you can explode it and extract the fields you need:

```py
data_json = df.withColumn("data", F.from_json("data", schema)) \
    .withColumn("data", F.explode("data")) \
    .select(F.col('id'), F.col('data.*'))
```

Result:

```
+---+-----+----------+----+
| id|  zip|  phnumber|name|
+---+-----+----------+----+
|  1|78910|5678910123|   -|
|  1|78920|5678910123|   -|
+---+-----+----------+----+
```